# java jdbc mysql: how to store credentials in properties file with special characters?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to MySQL using JDBC with a java program. The program reads from a properties file to get credentials (url,username,password). We use special characters such as ^,&,*,@ in the password.

a section of the properties file look something like this:

```
mysql.username=bob
mysql.password=th1$is^my@pa$$w*rd   (not the real password, but for the sake of discussion)
```

the error from the stack trace looks like this:
ERROR: unable to connect to db: [43008] Access denied: for user 'bob'@'' (using password: YES)

I confirmed that the program is able to read the password (by printing it to the console). It looks like it's some sort of escape sequence that is required that I'm missing?

have search google and asked some coworkers but no one seem to know the answer.

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to get the `mysql.password` property and how you use it in your program? The properties file supports the posted value. It could be that you're using a wrong user/password. As a last resource, post your password or the symbols in it.

Answer (score 1):

> the error from the stack trace looks like this: ERROR: unable to connect to db: [43008] Access denied: for user 'bob'@''

There's your answer, more specifically the **'bob'@''** snippet. Which tells you that the use bob at no host (or empty host) is trying to connect to your MySQL database, which I'm almost sure it's not what you are trying to do.

The solution lies in making sure you got the right url to connect to your database:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+HOST+"/" + DB; //Double check your HOST constant

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

**EDIT:**

It seems by the way that you are storing the pass the right way, the only characters you should scape in a property file are:

```
\t \n \r \\ \" \' \ (space) \= \:
```

Comment: I believe that you do not have to newInstanse(), this should be enough: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: This is not OP's problem but read the whole data in the properties file for the `mysql.password` entry.

Comment: seems like he's missing something like mysql.host @LuiggiMendoza. I mean, there's no problem to pass special characters via JDBC as password, but he won't connect without a host and that's what that snippet is telling

Comment: Read OP's question title: **how to store credentials in properties file with special characters?** I don't think the `DriverManager.getConnection` is the main problem for OP.

Comment: Anyway, just in case, I've put some characters that would make some difference in not being escaped

Comment: thanks for your responses. when i use standard characters, ie non special characters, my program will connect to (another) database. the problem is when i attempt to use the special characters to connect to the one that requires it.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using any of the characters I posted on my edit without escape? In your example the ones like ^ $ and @ should be ok to be unescaped. Also, if it's finishing with \ you should escape too, otherwise it can interpret it as a new line